# Can not mount internal driver in Archbang 2014

Tags: mount, fstab, archbang

I have just installed archbang 2014 on my laptop Asus K53SV. I followed the instruction on Archbang wiki. I have already installed `ntfs-3g`, but I can not access to the internal (ntfs-formatted) devices. The computer said that : **udevil: denied 88: device /dev/sda5 is an internal device and you're not root**
I have already install `udevil` also.

What is my problem? I heard that may be the etc/fstab is wrong, and here is mine:

```
#
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=9120f084-24b3-4047-b082-58a720a73433 / ext4 defaults 0 1
```

Here is the result after running `lsblk -f`

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                
├─sda1 ntfs   System Reserved 8E34628434626F61                     
├─sda2 ntfs                   16506B15506AFB3F                     
├─sda3 ext4                   9120f084-24b3-4047-b082-58a720a73433 /
├─sda4                                                             
├─sda5 ntfs   D               166016C36016A98F                     
└─sda6 ntfs   E               3A07C62FDB62B589                     
sr0
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What command are you using to mount them?

Comment: I just clicked on the icon in file browser mode.